# Properities of sine(and cosine) of Brownian Motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, conditional-expectation, martingales

Suppose $(B_t, \mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is a classical Brownian Motion (with the canonical filtration) and consider the process $X_t=\sin(B_t)$.

What properties does our new process share with a Brownian motion? Concretely: does it follow that $(X_t, \mathcal{F}_t)_{t \geq 0}$ is also a continous martingale?

It is definetively the case that $X_t$ also has stationary, independent increments, so that: $$\mathbb{E}[X_T|X_t] = \mathbb{E}[X_t + (X_T-X_t)|X_t] = X_t + \mathbb{E}[(X_T-X_t)|X_t] = X_t + \mathbb{E}[X_T-X_t] = X_t$$

Do you agree? Continuity also seems not difficult. On the other hand, the previous quick proof does not hold for $\cos(B_t)$ since $\mathbb{E}[X_T] \neq \mathbb{E}[X_t] \neq 0$.

Does this mean $\cos(B_t)$ is really not a martingale? I am using the results on this [page](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1625008/what-is-the-expected-value-of-cosine-of-a-multivariate-gaussian) by the way, for the expected values of $\sin(B_t)$ and $\cos(B_t)$.

Comment: Are you familiar with Itô's lemma?

Comment: A little bit, yes. I just took a look at the lemma again. If we prove that both process are Ito processes then we are done, right? @JoseAvilez

Comment: Not quite, as you probably want to show that $X$ is not a martingale (hint: it isn't). Your calculation of conditional expectation is suspect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuity is immediate as the composition of continuous functions is again continuous. However, $\sin (B_t)$ and $\cos (B_t)$ are not martingales.

Let $f(x) = \sin x$, so that $f_x(x) = \cos x$ and $f_{xx}(x) = -\sin x$.
Then, by Itô's lemma, $X_t$ satisfies the following stochastic differential equation:

$$dX_t = f_x(B_t) dB_t + \frac{1}{2}f_{xx}(B_t) dt = \cos (B_t)dB_t - \frac{1}{2} \sin (B_t)dt$$

In particular, $\sin B_t$ has a non-zero drift term, so that it cannot be a martingale. You may argue similarly for $\cos B_t$,

Comment: Thank you! Can I ask you one more thing: is $\sqrt{t} \sin(B_t)$ a martingale? I am reading about the Lemma, and maybe the $\sin$ cancels out there.

Comment: Although here https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Itos-Lemma/
the lemma is stated for $C^2$ functions, and the square root is not $C^2$ in $\mathbb{R}$..

Comment: I see. However, we would then have that $f(x,t)= \sqrt{t}\sin(x)$, and using the notation of the page https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Itos-Lemma/, $dW(t)^2$ is just $dB(t)^2$ which is $dt$. Adding them both does not give 0, so it still has a drift. Could you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Sarah The comment section is perhaps not the best place for us to have this conversation. Please post it as a separate question showing your application of Itô's lemma and I'll be able to comment.

Comment: Ok! Give me a second. Thank you for the discussion btw.

Comment: I posted the other question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4437903/prove-x-t-sqrttb-t-is-a-martingale-if-b-t-is-a-brownian-motion